# Var to html div creating list

Tags: jquery

Some info on the issue: I am trying to create a list that fills up with all the issues a person had with their password, I'm sure there are a million ways. However the way I am doing that is by using a `var` called `what` (which is defined earlier so that's not the issue) and having it take on the value of the `div` before it's cleared and then `what` + my new content is placed in the new `div`, and each if statement adds on. So if your password is missing everything, then a nice long list should show up.

I had this working before made some changes and now its not working again. Also please note I removed the `<li>` just to trouble shoot the issue. Oh, and what it does now is it runs through all the `if` statements and displays just the text of the last `if` statement that was false (so no list is created, however all the text of all the issues flashed quickly till the last one which stays.).

```
 $("#password").blur(function()
{

  if($('#password').val().length >= 6) {
      passlen = true; 
      checkSubmitStatus();}
    else{   
    what=$("box1").val(); 
      passlen= false;

      $("#box1").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        { 
         $(this).html(what +  'Password must be atleast 6 characters long!').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1); 
          });


  }

  if($('#password').val() != $('#username').val()) {
      passuse=true;
      checkSubmitStatus();}
      else{
          passuse= false; 
          what=$("#box1").val();  

        $("#box1").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        { 
          $(this).html(what +  'Password must be different from Username!').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1); 
          });  


  }
  re = /[0-9]/;
  if(re.test($('#password').val())) {
      passnum=true;
      checkSubmitStatus();}
      else{
          passnum= false;
        what=$("#box1").val(); 

    $("#box1").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        {   

         $(this).html(what +  'Password must contain at least one number (0-9)!').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1); 
          });


  }
  re = /[a-z]/;
  if(re.test($('#password').val())) {
      passlow=true;
      checkSubmitStatus();}
      else{
          passlow= false;
         what=$("#box1").val();  

    $("#box1").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        { 

         $(this).html(what +  'Password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1); 
          });


  }
  re = /[A-Z]/;
  if(re.test($('#password').val())) {
      passup=true;
      checkSubmitStatus();}
      else{
          passup=false;
          what=$("#box1").val(); 

          $("#box1").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        { 

         $(this).html(what +  'Password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1); 
          });

  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `<ul>` element and use jQuery's append/appendTo function.

```
var ul = $("ul");

if( /*password passes criterion*/ ) {
   flag = true;
   checkSubmitStatus();
} else {
   flag = false;
   $("<li></li>").html(errormessage).addClass("messageboxerror").appendTo(ul).fadeTo(900,1);
}

/*Repeat for each criterion*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully know if your question states that you want to provide a full list of validation errors, or only the first one encountered.

If all of them, I agree with Dennis' answer of creating a holding element (such as a  tag) and add

tags for each validation offense.  As each li is added, it will contain the validation along with a nice user experience fade-in with the .fade(900,1) addition.